# How can I dynamically change title and description in Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development

I am using Yoast for metas and thrive content builder for landing page design. I want to add dynamically utm parameters value in title and description. I tried in header.php and general-template.php but changes did not reflect in my landing page. Changes are reflected in home page, normal post and page but didn't reflect where I use thrive content builder page.

my url is http:// www. xyz.com/5-coolest-things/?utm=face
so I want to append this utm parameter value in my title page. I got this utm value and append in metas but didn't do this in landing page please help me...

Answer (score 0):

go Admin -> SEO menu -> Titles and Metas -> Post Type Tab 
You can create with use them; 
%%title%%
%%page%% 
%%sep%% 
%%sitename%%

Comment: thanks for your reply..but how can I get string parameter in title from this url http:// www. xyz.com/5-coolest-things/?utm=face?

Comment: go your posts on admin panel and edit it. you will see Yoast SEO meta fields under of that post you can edit your title there

Comment: Sorry I think that I am irritating you but I didn't get your point..there are meta fields but my question is that how can I add "face" from url to my title.  suppose my url is http:// www. xyz.com/5-coolest-things/?utm=face? and title was "how to do" at page creation time now I want page title should be "how to do - face"